# DB2 Driver with class - weblogic.jdbc.db2.DB2Driver missing for Weblogic 14c development version

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic

I installed developer version of weblogic 14c and looks like developer version doesn't has DB2 drivers pre installed as I get below errors after upgrading 12c domain using reconfig wizard ,

> CFGFWK-42066:Missing driver class

> Driver Class :weblogic.jdbc.db2.DB2Driver

[image]

Data sources were configured using this driver class in Weblogic 12C and I would like to reuse same JNDI datasources in Weblogic 14c as well without doing any modifications.

Package - `weblogic.jdbc.db2` belongs to Oracle & not IBM so I guess I must find relevant jar at some Oracle site.

Comment: Thrid party jdbc drivers are not always installed along with WebLogic server as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/jdbca/jdbc_datasources.html#GUID-670A75A5-0EAD-447D-9D02-C2A50D618933) Locate your JDBC driver in your WebLogic Server installation and add it to your classpath as described in the doc.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin: Thanks for input.Finding the relevant jar is the first challenge that I am facing, by looking at package `weblogic.jdbc.db2`, its seems Oracle should provide it & I have searched web extensively without any results. When I had installed 12c, the jar must have been pre installed because I didn't do any separate download etc. I think this light installer for 14c has missing drivers.

Comment: Check if oracle_common/modules/datadirect/wldb2.jar file exists in your installation

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin: **datadirect** directory is there in my 12c installation but not in 14c installation. On 12c, `wldb2.jar` is there.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin : I have copied full datadirect directory from my 12c installation to 14c & connection testing for predefined datasources in 12c is working fine now. I will accept if you can put an answer for what is discussed in comments. I simply wanted domain to be upgraded using reconfig without manually configuring JMS servers , datasources etc again.

Comment: Thx a lot.
Do you request for help about your domain upgrade ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin: no , domain upgrade is done successfully, thx .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thrid party jdbc drivers are not always installed along with WebLogic server as stated in the documentation Locate your JDBC driver in your WebLogic Server installation and add it to your classpath as described in the doc.
DB2 driver should be located in oracle_common/modules/datadirect/wldb2.jar file
If the jdbc driver is not present you can copy it from a full weblogic server installation.